# Smooth UITableView scrolling while calling reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using a method to get new item from web after user scrolls end of my UITableView.

when user hit end of list im calling my fetching class inside :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
```

to avoid ui freeze and get,parse  new item from Serve r.

there is no lag here , but when i try reload data inside my table and adding item to

list (reladData)  there is a minor hiccup is scrolling. its about 0.4 or 0.5 second and also

scrolling will be freezed during this time.

i even tried to use this method :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                                       {
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]
```

instead of normal reloadData but lag still apear.

is there anyway to avoid this , or should i create Message/progress animation or something

else to notify user during this lag like "please wait" pop up?

Comment: Are you adding a footer to the table with an activity indicator or similar so the user knows you're loading additional data? Do you expect the user to scroll away while it's happening?

Comment: Calling `reloadData` will complete reload the table view. All cells are removed and added again, thus this will cause noticeable lag. There are methods to add/remove/update tableview cell dynamically this will cause less lag.

Comment: @Wain if this lag is normal , then i guess the only solution is to add "please wait..." footer. is it possible to scroll way while this happening without lag?

Comment: @rckoenes oh thanks didnt know that, Could you please elaborate more about these "add/remove/update" method on cells ? any link or direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the docs: [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you will looking for [`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW38) ect.. But don't forget to call `beginUpdates` before the changes and `endUpdates` to commit them.